# UIButton to Navigation title

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I have Two ViewController with Navigation controller,
and i want to press different button to change to next page and Next title also change when i hit a different button?

used this method??

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {

            if Button == A;{
             self.title = @"A";
           }else Button == B {
             self.title = @"B";
    }

    - (IBAction)A:(id)sender {
        self.title =@"A";

    }

    - (IBAction)B:(id)sender {
        self.title =@"B";
    }
```

*I know this is a wrong way, cause it just change first page title,but i want to change the second page only,and i just want to description that what i want to do,
please help,
Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

Pass your string (Which you want to set on next View Controller) from your first view controller to next view controller and put this `self.title = Your passed string` in next view controller's `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: if i want to send in the same viewcontroller page,but different topic when i press different button?